# JDBC - Reuse Bind Variable in Query

Tags: java, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I have a SQL stmnt like the one below, and it it complaining because I am not passing in two bind variables.

Is there a way I can reuse the one bind variable, since they're the same?

```
String sqlText = "SELECT * FROM person WHERE (name = UPPER(?) OR name = LOWER(?) )";

List<obj> results = tmplt.query(sqlText, new Object[]{name}, new objExtractor());
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Use [NamedParameterJdbcTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html) and assign the same name to both parameters:

```
SELECT * FROM person WHERE (name = UPPER(:param) OR name = LOWER(:param) )
```

More explanations on how to use this class in [the documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#jdbc-NamedParameterJdbcTemplate).

Comment: I've used it before, but had forgotten about it. Thanks!